# How to fix Expected $.length = 2 to equal 1

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine-marbles

I want to test ngLogger function with jasmine marble but a got error

```
Expected $.length = 2 to equal 1.

Expected $.length = 2 to equal 1.

Expected $[0].frame = 0 to equal 10.

Expected $[0].notification.value to be a kind of Observable, but was Object({ type: 'TECHNICAL', level: 'ERROR', msg: 'test' }).

Expected $[1] = Object({ frame: 0, notification: Notification({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false }) }) to equal undefined.
```

### Test:

```js
    export namespace GlobalUtils {
       export function ngLogger(error: string): 
                                   Observable<Log> {
        return of({ type: LogEnum.TECHNICAL,
          level: LevelEnum.ERROR,
          msg: error } as Log
        );
      }
    }



    import { GlobalUtils } from './global.utils';

    it('ngLogger should be return an Observable', () => {
        const expected = of({
          type: LogEnum.TECHNICAL,
          level: LevelEnum.ERROR,
          msg: 'test'
        });

        const expected$ = hot('-a', { a: expected });
        const result$ = GlobalUtils.ngLogger('test');

        expect(result$).toBeObservable(expected$);
      });
```

`const expected$ = hot('a', { a: expected });` don't do any difference. `const expected$ = hot('a|', { a: expected });` give the error :

```js
    Expected $[0].notification.value to be a kind of Observable, but was Object({ type: 'TECHNICAL', level: 'ERROR', msg: 'test' }).
    Expected $[1].frame = 0 to equal 10
```

then I changed

```js
const expected = of({
      type: LogEnum.TECHNICAL,
      level: LevelEnum.ERROR,
      msg: 'test'
    });` to `const expected = of({
      type: LogEnum.TECHNICAL,
      level: LevelEnum.ERROR,
      msg: 'test'
    });
```

I get the error `Expected $[1].frame = 0 to equal 10.` 
what does it means ?

Comment: `const expected$ = hot('a', { a: expected });` or even `const expected$ = hot('a|', { a: expected });`?

Comment: `const expected$ = hot('a', { a: expected });` don't do any difference.

Comment: now i see you have 2 issues first is that marble should be `(a|)` as this is how you describe simultaneous emit and end observable which is done when using `of` second issue is that you have your expected defined as observable and it should be only the data inside

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have 2 issues first is that marble should be `(a|)` as this is how you describe simultaneous emit and end observable which is done when using `of`.
The second issue is that you have your expected defined as observable and it should be only the data inside.
And thanks to this I have learnt how to use marbles:

```js
const msg = 'test';
const expected = {
  type: LogEnum.TECHNICAL,
  level: LevelEnum.ERROR,
  msg,
}; // notice that this value should not be observable

const expected$ = hot('(a|)', { a: expected }); // also you are returning of which is ending immediately

const result$ = GlobalUtils.ngLogger(msg);

expect(result$).toBeObservable(expected$);
```

Also in addition here is [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-testing-marbles-weqr)